# How to conceptualize unintuitive topology?

Tags: general-topology, soft-question, recreational-mathematics, advice, origami

I found [*Project Origami: Activities for Exploring Mathematics*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1466567910) in my university's library the other day and quickly FUBAR'd (folded-up beyond all recognition) the couple sheets of paper I had with me at the time.

I showed the book to a couple friends who have studied some topology, and we looked at one project with the goal of creating a double torus out of paper. Apparently, it's possible to make one out of an octagon of the infinitely stretchable material of topology-land following a diagram like this:

[image: octagon]

Just connect the edges labelled with the same letters so that the arrows point the same way, and there's a double torus.

I had trouble conceptualizing how the surface contorted in 3-space, even though I could understand why joining an octagon's edges like that makes a double torus (two [single torus diagrams](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~mec/Winter2009/Victor/part1(6).png) joined at a corner, stretched into a diagonal of the octagon).

My question is: what can I do to improve my conceptual understanding of what's going on? If I didn't know what a single torus diagram looked like, I'd have no clue what the octagon diagram was creating.

Is there some kind of software that will let me play around with infinitely-stretchable material and join edges?

Anywhere I can order really stretchy origami paper?

Comment: *Don't* conceptualize unintuitive things. Work with the definitions until you understand it sufficiently to develop ineffable intuition on your own.

Answer (score 5):

I'm no topologist, I just like to sketch things.

[image]

We know that the $ca$ loop can be pinched apart like that because the endpoints of the other $a$ and $c$ segments are identified already.

Now it just remains to attach two handles to connect $a$ to $a$ and $c$ to $c$.

Comment: These sketches definitely helped me see it, thanks!