# Is there some kind of software that will let me play around with infinitely-stretchable material and join edges?

Tags: general-topology, math-software

This question has been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/934579/how-to-conceptualize-unintuitive-topology) as part of a different question about visualizing a particular space, but the answer focused on the particular case and not on this sub-question. A software tool to stretch and smush surfaces would be a neat way of studying some topological spaces.

Apologies in advance if this is off-topic.